# Special domain for a page

Tags: urls, htaccess, rewrite-rules, domain

I have a wp instalation on `example.com` and want to have `secondary.com` to show contents of `example.com/b` (b is a page) but keep `secondary.com` in the url (not secondary.com/b)

I tried this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35272993/2095642

I have both domains pointed to one directory, I use this in my **wp-config.php**:

```
//this works, enables both domains to show the same wp installation
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

and this in my .htaccess:

```
#this works, changes example.com/b url to secondary.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.com$
RewriteRule ^b/(.*)$ https://www.secondary.com/$1 [L,QSA,R=302]

#this doesn't take effect and shows homepage on secondary.com
#I want it to keep only secondary.com in URL but show page /b/.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} secondary.com/?$
RewriteRule ^$ /b/ [L,QSA]
```

The second rule works as it should when pointed to a non-wp directory - retains url but shows directory's index. But when pointed to a wp page path, it doesn't.

Thanks!

Comment: "`RewriteRule ^$ /b/ [L,QSA]`" - The problem here is the way WP routes URLs. Whilst you internally rewrite the request to `/b/` (or should that be `/b`?) - WordPress itself still sees the initial URL that was requested (the value of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` PHP superglobal). This will need some PHP coding. OR you can take a different route and configure a reverse proxy, but this potentially requires access to your server config.

Answer (score 2):

There is a plugin that does exactly this:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-domain-mapping-on-single-site

Anyway, it would be nicer to have things under control with an understandable few lines of script, so I'm still open to answers